# Rest Api || Codeigniter || Authorisation not defined

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the Rest server in my codeigniter project .

he rest server used is below

```
namespace chriskacerguis\RestServer;
```

I am getting Authorisation not found issue. In my rest.php file which is located in the application/config folder i have made the following changes.

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';
$config['auth_source'] = '';

This was not working . 
Then i added the code below in the .htaccess folder . 
*<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]*
```

This was also not working.

Need the way to resolve this issue . I tried making the above changes in the rest.php file only from the config folder .It is not working . 
Then made the required changes in the ht access file . In that case i am getting page not found issue .

Answer (score 0):

> **Remove** the **basic** when you **didn't used any Authorisation**

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';
```

> into

```
$config['rest_auth'] = false;
```

Comment: we have used authentication so login and password is there.

$config['rest_auth'] = false;
we was using this but still we use to get error

Comment: then you should pass username and password in the array of rest_valid_logins

Comment: check the example here https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-rest-api-user-login-registration/

Comment: I have already  added $config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'] before . Still its not working .

Comment: are you using postman  or anything else , pass the credentials in authorization section